# How do we use generics in React components with types derived from a hash map?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, type-conversion

I have a project where I am using basically the same component in several places in my app. I am trying to remove some of that redundant code by creating a generic component that support these existing use case. Each of these components use a Type which are extended from the same base type and I would like to provide a "type" value as an always provided prop in my component and then use this "type" in a hashmap to determine what props this component should use. However I am running into typing issues when using my "type" prop to determine the props of the component.

In order to support multiple types, I have created an enum with all of the value for the "type" value.

```
export enum Shape{
    SQUARE = "square",
    CIRCLE = "circle",
    RECTANGLE = "rectangle"
}
```

Then I have created interfaces for these types and a hash map to link the enum values to the type.

```
export interface SquareComponent{
    side: number;
    color: string;
}

export interface CircleComponent{
    radius: number;
    color: string;
}

export interface RectangleComponent{
    length: number;
    height: number;
    color: string;
}


//Hash map to get the type using an enum value
export type ShapeConversion = {
    [T in Shape]: {
        [Shape.SQUARE]: SquareComponent;
        [Shape.CIRCLE]: CircleComponent;
        [Shape.RECTANGLE]: RectangleComponent;
    }[T]
}
```

Next I created my interface for my ReactComponent with a generic.

```
export interface myComponentProps<T>{
    type: Shape, 
    shapeList: T[]
}
```

So when I create my component the typing works fine with one of my defined interfaces (like CircleComponent)

```
//This is OK
const myComponent = ({type, shapeList}:myComponentProps<CircleComponent>)=>{
   // does something with shapes
}
```

It also works fine when I create my component using the ShapeConversion hash map and I specify the shape directly.

```
//This is also OK
const myComponent2 = ({type, shapeList}:myComponentProps<ShapeConversion[Shape.CIRCLE]>)=>{
    // does something with shapes
 }
```

However I would like to be able to use the provided type prop to determine the result of the ShapeConversion hash map, but that is not working.

```
//This is not Ok
// Gives a typescript error "Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type."
const myComponent3 = ({type, shapeList}:myComponentProps<ShapeConversion[typeof type]>)=>{
    // does something with shapes
 }
```

Is there a way I can use an always provided prop, like type, to determine the props for my generic component?

Comment: Would you like to have a relation between `type` and `shapeList`? Currently you can have `type: Circle`  and `shapeList`with `RectangleComponent`

Comment: Yes. There should be a relationship between between type and shapelist. So if I had a type of Shape.Circle, it should only have a shapeList with a type of CircleComponent[]. That's true I am not accounting for that at all at this point in myComponentProps.

Comment: Then I would suggest doing something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7qarW). Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay will write the answer soon

Comment: I am not sure why the answer was unselected. I was just trying to upvote it since it was helpful to me. I believe it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing the `MyComponentProps` to accept a shape, not the type for the `MyComponentProps.shapeList`. This will allow us to link the value of `type` with the `shapeList` using the `ShapeConversion`:

```
type MyComponentProps<T extends Shape> = {
  type: T;
  shapeList: ShapeConversion[T][];
};
```

However, if you don't want to specify the shape manual then we should create a union of possible props using [union distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type MyComponentProps<T extends Shape = Shape> = T extends T
  ? {
      type: T;
      shapeList: ShapeConversion[T][];
    }
  : never;
```

Example:

```
// {
//     type: Shape.CIRCLE;
//     shapeList: CircleComponent[];
// }
type CircleProps = MyComponentProps<Shape.CIRCLE>;

// {
//     type: Shape.CIRCLE;
//     shapeList: CircleComponent[];
// } | {
//     type: Shape.SQUARE;
//     shapeList: SquareComponent[];
// } | {
//     type: Shape.RECTANGLE;
//     shapeList: RectangleComponent[];
// }
type AnyPossibleProps = MyComponentProps;
```

Usage:

```
//This is OK
const myComponent = ({ type, shapeList }: MyComponentProps<Shape.CIRCLE>) => {
  // does something with shapes
};

//This is OK
const myComponent2 = ({ type, shapeList }: MyComponentProps) => {
  // does something with shapes
};


// no error
myComponent2({
  type: Shape.CIRCLE,
  shapeList: [
    {
      radius: 1,
      color: 'ref',
    },
  ],
});

// expected error
myComponent2({
  type: Shape.CIRCLE,
  shapeList: [
    {
      side: 1,
      color: 'ref',
    },
  ],
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoAsCGZhwDeAUHJgIoCqAggEoCicAvHAOQDOAjsjlMKwBpScAMIBJWiIAyjFqwDGASyjyANvyFkGIgCrUAcgHEZzNn3kwciAObrBxAL7FioSLDiLEMYFABmOeQIMbl5gEQhUSEQkeBIydkUAE2AALjgUVAAjHwBuYXkIVWg09hgoT2s8pxdwaHhPbz8AghFlNTCIqJiiYSgcRMVkdjSM7Kg8sgKiqBKyiqrnVzqPLx9-QLhaYAsrWw7IiGivHrJ1GywYEbQxibgsYEVrC6us3PzC4rhS8psF4gB6f4ACRw7CwcFQeDgMAgcGswHgMHu0IAnvg4EMKnArAgMnAAG44VTIYA1NyItFBXD4cKIfE+BKHUxxOAAbR0K0w1OAAF00iyyKzsHhgAA6DBUOj0PmYEJ8cIHI4wW6C4X4UXiSQyGWtFTqBVdLwqtlqsXaPRGbVpLY7Gz6zqHGK3BzsnlVPJk5YwSlwACyKINjq8AAUoBAwOwADwc0DeRCJdhckWmU0APlMMZAcYTcB0wgA-CcyMXvfg0jpjfFuVJFKU0qbafSoIzEK7WW7hGQnGQRsAmx7ATosLWPImAPIAaWIBUQpQhAYdStMAApCKj8AIvtXa-AHGl-YGlaHw1HTRqJNJ6KmAJTMdMswFwRIQYCJ9gRBHDmxwADuiiRW4iuwjgDv8Q4jiOk7Tocc6oAuioxAATCua6lsAm5giKNZznufrwYaMDHhGt5MPewiPs+r5fB+SJYn+AGYfgwEOKB6Swj4YZQMQcGHkhq7CGh9bcueWr0JogH4Nhlxsp2RbFnAfQDEMaQAIzifJUyfKwfC+PY8kOOJPJCA416sa42zeIkCBQJx3H4UGMCIfxZCCUm6qape4mMcAUlpKyskCsWCTJKp6nFppMxmMAulhQZwhGY4pnEEAA)